# Find the difference in days between a java.util.Date and a Joda-Time DateTime?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Is it possible to find the difference (preferably expressed in terms of the number of days) between a `java.util.Date` and a Joda-Time `DateTime`?

```
class ReminderInterval{
    //it will return a last login date(java.util.Date)
    Date lastDate=Obj.getAccepted();

    //it is Joda-Time type
    DateTime currentDate=new DateTime();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just convert `Date` to `DateTime` and then use [`Days#daysBetween()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29). The `DateTime` has a [constructor](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29) taking the time in millis and the `Date` has a [getter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) returning exaclty that.

```
DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(Obj.getAccepted().getTime());
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
int days = Days.daysBetween(lastDate, currentDate).getDays();
```